# Jetpack Connection Broken

Tags: dashboard, plugin-jetpack

I've upgraded from 2.8.4 to 3.1.2. There were [a number of issues](http://www.notoriouswebmaster.com/2011/05/16/when-wordpress-goes-wrong/), which are now largely resolved. But Jetpack continues to be problematic. I keep getting this error message in the stats block on the dashboard:

> unknown_token: It looks like your Jetpack connection is broken. Try disconnecting from WordPress.com then reconnecting.

I've found no references to this issue on the web. (Except for a Greek translation in Automattic's svn archive.)

So, I tried logging in and out of WordPress.com. I also cleared out the cookies in my blog and in wordpress.com. All to no avail.

Has anybody seen this error? Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oops. OK, I figured it out. I'll blame it on UX: there _is_ a button on Jetpack's very ornate admin page which allows you to connect and disconnect from WordPress.com. But the button is very closely matched to the colour of the background, and the microcopy is a little confusing. But I'll cop to a mea culpa. Sorry for wasting your bandwidth.

Comment: Make that an answer, and add a little screenshot. Someone else may have the same problem and shouldn’t find an unanswered question.

Answer (score 2):

Oops. OK, I figured it out. I'll blame it on UX: there is a button on Jetpack's very ornate admin page which allows you to connect and disconnect from WordPress.com. But the button is very closely matched to the colour of the background, and the microcopy is a little confusing. But I'll cop to a mea culpa. Sorry for wasting your bandwidth.

(I would've posted a screenshot, but I'm a new user on this site, and need 10 Whuffie points before I can do that.)